# How to convert OpenSSL SHA-512 hash to GMP number to use in RSA encryption method

Tags: c, rsa, gmp, sha512

```
SHA1(data, length, hash);
unsigned char *labelPtr;

labelPtr = hash;
mpz_set_str (encrypted, labelPtr, 16);
gmp_printf("hashed= %Zd\n", encrypted);
```

`encrypted` equals 0?
I need to get an integer from this hash so that I can perform RSA encryption.  I see the hash when I debug, but cannot seem to turn this into an `int`. It is SHA-512 so 512 bits? 
Weird characters come out of `printf("%s",hash);`
`atoi` gives 0 too, do I have to break up the hash by character? That would work I think.

Comment: I see `SHA1` and `SHA1` is 160-bit.

Comment: yes sha1 is smaller but 512 is more secure and gmp should be able to handle it

Comment: That's not the point, you mention `SHA-512` but your program is using a `SHA1` function.

Comment: no this is open ssh so you can define sha 512 unsigned char hash[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];

Comment: sha_digest_length in open ssl defines sha 1 which is 160 bit or 256 or 512 i defined it as 512

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mpz_set_str` second parameter must be a string.

The `hash` argument you pass to `SHA1` function is probably not a string. Convert it to a string format before passing it to the `mpz_set_str` function.

Comment: \355\020\ is the value in the hash after

Comment: if i use print f wierd characters come out printf("%s",hash); so im sure its a string... just very wierd atoi gives 0 too, do i have to break up the hash by character because that would work i think

Comment: @Thefirstkilla `mpz_set_str (encrypted, labelPtr, 16)` requires you to have a string and basis 16 to be used. Your string should be printable: you have to convert your array to a string with basis 16 values. You can use `sprintf` to do that.