# Encrypting SHA512 Example in c

Tags: c, sha512

I can't find an example of encrypting a string with "SHA-512" in C.
Can someone help me with some code or a link.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: SHA 512 is not an encryption algorithm. Rather it's used for hashing. Where are you stuck? What are you really trying to do?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772102/how-to-convert-openssl-sha-512-hash-to-gmp-number-to-use-in-rsa-encryption-metho) on SO.

Answer (score 15):

SHA-512 is not an encryption algorithm, it is a [*cryptographic hash*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash), which is completely different.

One library you can use to perform SHA hashes is [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/).  Here's an example of computing the raw SHA-512 hash of some data with OpenSSL:

```
#include <openssl/sha.h>
...
char data[] = "data to hash";
char hash[SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];
SHA512(data, sizeof(data) - 1, hash);

// 'hash' now contains the raw 64-byte binary hash.  If you want to print it out
// in a human-readable format, you'll need to convert it to hex, e.g.
```

Comment: Helpful answer! However, I think you need to do sizeof(data)-1 to exclude the terminating null character.

Comment: @JustinB yeah or he could use `strlen(data)`

Answer (score 7):

If you want to store passwords using SHA-512, please consider using a "salt" value to make rainbow-table attacks harder. Example, "12345678" would be a random string. "$6$" marks SHA-512:

```
#include <crypt.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char *hash = crypt("secret", "$6$12345678$");
    printf("hashed=%s\n", hash);
}
```

Comment: Thank u for the answer, i've found an SHA1 code, ans i used it, it's better than MD5 and still strong too. i will use salts values with the passwords and store the hashes in a file, only the super user can access that file. If i'm wrong correct me .

Comment: `char *hash = crypt("secret", "$6$12345678");` This seems to be missing a '$' at the end of the salt. Format: `$6$<salt>$<hashed secret>`.  That is also what I've seen in many other examples.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I edited the example. Both produce the same result in Linux, though.

Answer (score 6):

You can use GLib for this matter, be aware of G_CHECKSUM_SHA512, it might require you to install a newer version of GLib, visit: https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Data-Checksums.html

```
#include <glib.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(void)
{
        char   *string  = "Hello World";
        gchar  *sha512;

        sha512 = g_compute_checksum_for_string(G_CHECKSUM_SHA512, string, strlen(string));
        g_print("%s\n", sha512);
        g_free(sha512);
        return 0; 
}
```

compile

```
$ gcc -o sha512 sha512.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0`
```